# R populate column based on several criteria

Tags: r

I have a dataset in which I want to create a new  column that takes existing values from another column when available, when no values are available, it should instead take values one year in the past.

Example, I have the following data:

```
Date      Market   Campaign    Impressions
1/1/2017  SE       Home        150
1/2/2017  SE       Home        100
1/1/2017  GB       Home        50
1/2/2017  GB       Home        55
1/1/2018  SE       Home        NA
1/2/2018  SE       Home        NA
```

I would like to write something that will provide me with:

```
Date      Market   Campaign    Impressions  Future_impressions
1/1/2017  SE       Home        150          150
1/2/2017  SE       Home        100          100
1/1/2017  GB       Home        50           50
1/2/2017  GB       Home        55           55
1/1/2018  SE       Home        NA           150
1/2/2018  SE       Home        NA           100
```

I have managed to populate Future_impressions with the Impressions for historic months using:

```
df$Future_impressions[is.na(df$Impressions)] <- NA
```

But I have no idea how get the future months populated. I basically want to write something that says: 
- IF Impressions=NA
- THEN MATCH (Date minus 12 months) AND MATCH Market and Campaign and retrieve Impressions

I am a very new R user but I've searched around extensively, so I hope I haven't asked a redundant question!

Thank you all so much in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an option using `apply`

```
df$Date <- as.Date(df$Date,'%m/%d/%Y')

get.last.year <- function(dt, mk, cp){
  ly <- as.POSIXlt(dt)
  ly$year <- ly$year - 1
  ly <- as.Date(ly)
  x <- df[df$Date == ly & 
         df$Market == mk & 
         df$Campaign == cp, "Impressions"]
  return(x)
}

df$Future.impressions <- apply(df, 1, function(x) ifelse(!is.na(x[["Impressions"]]), x[["Impressions"]], get.last.year(x[["Date"]], x[["Market"]], x[["Campaign"]])))
```

Comment: Amazing answer in base R. +1

Comment: Wonderful! Thank you Matt! You have made my day :) 

If anyone else finds this useful but would like to rerun the script to generate values for more metrics, note that you have to specify origin for the POSIXlt-variable. I did it as `as.POSIXlt(dt, origin = "2016-06-01")` 
I am not sure why or what the actual origin date should be, but this worked for me.